# Android fragment commit already called

Tags: android

Мне необходимо заменить фрагмент, при получении данных. 
Данные приходят в @JavascriptInterface и вызывают метод

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void sayHello(String type) {

    CheatActivity.fTrans.replace(R.id.frgmCont, MainActivity.frag2).commit();

}
```

Т.к. в главном активити запущен изначально commit фрагмента, получаю ошибку из заголовка.
Необходимо каждый раз указывать начало транзакции с фрагментом

```
fTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Но getSupportFragmentManager() выдает ошибку, при использовании в @JavascriptInterface

Если создаю метод в MainActivity, который будет менять фрагменты, при вызове из 
@JavascriptInterface, то метод необходимо сделать static. А getSupportFragmentManager(), не работает в данном случае.

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:gravity="center">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frgmCont"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="479dp">
    </FrameLayout>...
```

MainActivity

```
public static Fragment1 frag1;
    public static Fragment2 frag2;
    public static FragmentTransaction fTrans; 

       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);

            frag1 = new Fragment1();
            frag2 = new Fragment2();

    ...


            fTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fTrans.replace(R.id.frgmCont, frag1).commit();
```

UPD

```
public class JsInterface {
    Context mContext;


    JsInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void sayHello(String type) {

        CheatActivity.fTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        CheatActivity.fTrans.replace(R.id.frgmCont, CheatActivity.frag2).commit();

    }
```

Comment: А что за ошибка при вызове getSupportFragmentManager в JavascriptInterface? И где, в каком классе, описан последний?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб , сделал апдейт. Думаю, что я не правильно вызываю getSupportFragmentManager(). cannot  resolve method

Comment: В классе JsInterface нет доступа к классу активити и засим нет метода getSupportFragmentManager. Попробуйте сделать этот класс внутренним классом класса активити. Или скастовать mContext к классу активити (если это активити) и тогда из него вызывать getSupportFragmentManager